# C6387 warning with WTSEnumerateSessionsEx

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, warnings

I am receiving the C6387 warning while trying to call `WTSEnumerateSessionsEx`. Here is my code (which works as expected):

```
WTS_SESSION_INFO_1* info=NULL;
DWORD info_count = 0;
DWORD level = 1;
WTSEnumerateSessionsEx(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, &level, 0, &info, &info_count);
```

Can anyone explain what is happening and how to fix this?

Here is the screenshot from Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

Comment: But what not clear in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6387 ? By annotation api not wait for 0 in first argument but you pass 0. This is simply bad annatation. Ignore this warning

Comment: Thanks for toy answer, RbMm. I was pretty sure they count arguments from zero and thought the problem is in "level". Now I see that WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE is NULL. I will try to report wrong annotation to MS.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by RbMm, this is a misleading function annotation. I have filled a [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/WTSEnumerateSessionsEx-false-positive-C6/1524691) to MS and hope they will fix it some day. As for now the warning is suppressed this way:

```
#pragma warning(suppress: 6387)
WTSEnumerateSessionsEx(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, &level, 0, &info, &info_count);
```

Comment: You should amend your report to include a solution - the first parameter should be annotated as `_In_opt_` rather than `_In_`